# Comparing classifications based on different features with McNemar test

Tags: classification, mcnemar-test

I have a classification task where I need to classify several land cover classes (such as forest, grass, water, etc.) based on two different sets of features (predictors). The first set of features comprises two spectral characteristics. The second set of features comprises the same two spectral characteristics plus two more texture characteristics. I want to know if the difference in accuracy (the percentage correct classified samples) for these two datasets is significant. May I use the [McNemar](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/mcnemar/) test of proportions in this case? My final idea is to find if adding texture can improve classification results.

Also, as I know, for regression tasks, it is important how many predictors there is in the model - that is why we use Adjusted R squared and AIC, right. Is there a need to account for the number of predictors in classification tasks?

Comment: What kind of classification model are you using?

Comment: @Dave I am using Random Forest.

Answer (score 2):

McNemar is only for binary outcomes (0,1), (1,2) or test results (+,-), and thus two classes, not multiclass.  A multiclass test for two classifers can be performed using Cohen's kappa.  However, Cohen's kappa suffers from imbalanced class sample sizes, called Cohen's kappa paradox. Margineantu and Dietterich [1] introduced a paradox-resilient kappa defined as
\begin{equation}
\kappa=\frac{\Theta_1 - \Theta_2}{1-\Theta_2},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\Theta_1= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^L C_{ii}}{n},
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\Theta_2=\sum_{i=1}^L \left( \frac{\sum_{j=1}^L C_{ij}}{n} \right) \left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^L C_{ji}}{n} \right).
\end{equation}
In the above formulation, $n$ is the number of test objects, $L$ is the number of class labels, $C_{ii}$ is the number of objects both classifiers voted for class $i$, and $C_{ij}$ is the number of objects for which the first classifier voted for class $i$ and the second classifier voted for class $j$.  Smaller $\kappa$ values indicate a larger diversity and when $\kappa= 0$, the agreement between two classifiers is based on chance, whereas when $\kappa=1$, the two classifiers agree on every example.

1. D. Margineantu, T. Dietterich. Pruning adaptive boosting. Proc. 14th Int. Conf. Machine Learning. San Francisco(CA), Morgan Kaufmann Press, 1997.

Comment: @ wjktrs Thanks for this information. I did not know about this publication. I may have it a try. Regarding the McNemar test, it is usual in my field, for example, see [here](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/asprs/pers/2004/00000070/00000005/art00006?crawler=true) to compact the multiclass error matrix to a 2 by 2 matrix - you just consider if the data points are correct or not ignoring the class. In this case, can I use the Mcnemar test?

Comment: Yes, since there are two (binary) outcomes: correct classification, incorrect.  Now that you can use McNemar, you have the advantage that McNemar is a test; the above Kappa is not a test. However, Fleiss' Kappa does have a test.